# How do i pass some arguments into a struct component?

Tags: swift, struct, swiftui, arguments, parameter-passing

How do i pass some arguments into a struct component?

What I am trying to do :
"I am new to Swiftui"
I have created a struct button component in order to have a different button colour when clicked and i am trying to pass a @State variable so that when the button is clicked the @State variable will be updated but i don't know how to pass an argument

```swift
struct ContentView: View {

   @State var currentCalcToChange:Int = 0;


    var body: some View {
      
      CustomButton(currentCalc: currentCalcToChange); // <--- this don't work obviously but is an illustration of what i want to do

  }
}



struct CustomButton: View {
@State private var didTap:Bool = false
@State var currentCalc:Int;
    
  var body: some View {

        Button(String(currentCalc), action: {
            currentCalc += 100
            self.didTap = true
            
        })
    .background(didTap ? Color.blue : Color.yellow)
  }
}
```

Comment: use: `CustomButton(currentCalc: currentCalc)` and don't use `;` at all. Read the basics of Swift at: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html 
and do the SwiftUI tutorial at: https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/

Comment: Okej maybe i wasn't clear , i have change the code a bit to try be more clear. What i want to achieve is to change the variable currentCalcToChange not the currentCalc witch is in the scope of the struct. But i don't know how to pass it?
is sound a bit weird to me. 
What do i pass the address of the @State variable inside a struct?

Comment: just use `@Binding var currentCalc:Int` in `CustomButton` and use `CustomButton(currentCalc: $currentCalcToChange)`. Also read the basics of Swift at: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html and do the SwiftUI tutorial at: https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/  and don't use `;` at all.

Comment: Thank you, your comment solved my question. now i am going to read the link that you have sent me to understand what the "$" infront of a variable do and @Binding

Comment: If you are struggling with the basic concepts of `@State`, `@Binding` and the `$`, you really need to
do the tutorial at: https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/

Comment: Thank you ++++ will now look  at the tutorial link from apple